# Spark: strange behavoir of partitionBy, field becomes unreadable

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a csv record, and I imported as a dataframe :

```
--------------------------- 
name | age | entranceDate | 
---------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 2019-10-01   | 
---------------------------
Mary | 15  | 2019-10-01   | 
---------------------------
```

And when I use :

```
String[] partitions =
new String[] {
  "name",
  "entranceDate"
};

df.write()
.partitionBy(partitions)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.parquet(parquetPath);
```

It writes my parquet into file (.parquet). But the strange thing is, when I try to read from the parquet again :

```
public static StructType createSchema() {
    final StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
            DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("entranceDate", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    ));
    return schema;
}


sqlContext.read()
    .schema(createSchema())
    .parquet(pathToParquet);
    .show()
```

The field `name` becomes unreadable :

```
|          name |  age | entranceDate|
+--------------------+----+
|?F...|Tom| 2019-10-01 | 
|?F...|Mary| 2019-10-01 |
+--------------------+
```

How is that possible ? But I tried if I don't put the `.partitionBy(partitions)` line, I can read without any problem.

Could someone explain what is the root cause ? I've been searching for a while but didn't find the cause.

**EDIT** : I tried to retrieve the "name" field (`row.getString(0)`), and I get the value as below but I can't read it :

```
?F??m???9??A?Aorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/UnsafeRowWriter??:??A?Aorg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter??!:??A?Aorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/UnsafeRowWriter??7:??A?Aorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/UnsafeRowWriter?-??9????Q:??A?Forg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/BaseGenericInternalRow$class??h:??,??A?Forg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class?????:??A?Forg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/BaseGenericInternalRow$class]??6x]???:???:???]??:??????x?:??????b?x?:?????c?x?:?????r?x?:?????c?x?:?????1c?x?:???????x?:?????.??x?:?????Nc?x?:?????]c?x?:????????x?:???????x?:????????x?:???????x?:????????x?:???????xy?x????:??]??X;??T???????:???:??????:???5??x?:???5?.???:???x????:??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???:??A?Eorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$2??
;???;?A?Eorg.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$2????#;??A?Eorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/trees/TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$2???j?v9??:???:??:???:??7;??9;???<?;;??>;?????H;???"?@?x?i?xux?]?E;???"?@?x?i?xux????:??;??????:???5??x[;???5?.??[;???x???c;??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9?h;???:?h;??[;??s;??u;???<?w;??z;??????;???"?egx?i?xux?]??;???"?egx?i?xux???h;???;??????:???5??b?x?;???5?.???;???b?x????;??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9??;???:??;??;??;??;???<??;??;??????;???"?o_x?i?xux?]??;???"?o_x?i?xux????;??<??????:???5?c?x?;???5?.???;??c?x????;??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9??;???:??;???;???;???;???<??;???;??????;???"??lx?i?xux?]??;???"??lx?i?xux????;??H<??????:???5?r?x<???5?.??<??r?x???<??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9?<???:?<??<??'<??)<???<?+<??.<?????8<???"?;_x?i?xux?]?5<???"?;_x?i?xux???<??<??????:???5?c?xK<???5?.??K<??c?x???S<??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9?X<???:?X<??K<??c<??e<???<?g<??j<?????t<???"?H_x?i?xux?]?q<???"?H_x?i?xux???X<???<??????:???5?1c?x?<???5?.???<??1c?x????<??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9??<???:??<??<??<??<???<??<??<??????<???"?|_x?i?x?/x?]??<???"?|_x?i?x?/x????<???<??????:???5???x?<???5?.???<???x????<??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9??<???:??<???<???<???<???<??<???<??????<???"??_x?i?x?/x?]??<???"??_x?i?x?/x????<??8=??????:???5?.??x?<???5?.???<??.??x???=??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9?=???:?=???<??=??=???<?=??=?????(=???"?T_x?i?xux?]?%=???"?T_x?i?xux???=??t=??????:???5?Nc?x;=???5?.??;=??Nc?x???C=??K0?i?x?i?x??6x6x??6x6x???j?v9?H=???:?H=??;=??S=??U=???<?W=??Z=?????d=???"?{lx?i?xux?]?a=???"?{lx?i?xux???H=??=??????:???5?]c?xw=???5?.??w=??]c?x???=??K0?i?x
```

Comment: are you sure `age` is a String? From the last statement, it seems somehow that age and name got mixed up (name is in age column)

Comment: hi, it’s just for example because I can’t paste my real data here, but yes these three columns are all of type string

Comment: I've run exactly your code and what I got:

`
    +---+----+------------+
    |age|name|entranceDate|
    +---+----+------------+
    | 11| Tom|  2019-10-01|
    | 15|Mary|  2019-10-01|
    +---+----+------------+
`

Comment: hi, I don't know if you can reproduce the error because i'm running the job on 4 executors, but it's what i'm getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns are getting mixed up because of the way `partitionBy` saves the file.
All the columns specified in the `partitionBy` clause gets stored as a directory structure.
In your case it would be like:

```
<<root-path>>/name=???/entranceDate=???/???.parquet
```

This enforces that the partition columns are specified towards the end of the schema in `L->R` order of directories.

So, while reading your parquet file if you specify the schema as `[age, name, entranceDate]`, it should yield proper values.

Comment: Hi I found your explanation very interesting but I don't quite get it, I indeed specify the schema when reading file, why the name field gets corrupted ?

Comment: I added the "name" field value in detail, could you have a look ? thanks very much

Comment: Well, let me rephrase it.. this behavior happens because the position of columns change when you partition the Dataset. The `name` column is now after `age` column

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: if you could help with this I'll be very grateful ! https://stackoverflow.com/q/58064097/5035236

Comment: in fact my "entranceDate" changes type to Date automatically after partitionBy, if I remove this it stays in type String, why ?

Comment: this happens because the partitioned columns' datatype is implicitly inferred.

Comment: and since your date value is in the default date format `YYYY-MM-DD` it is read as `date` implicitly. Had your date been in a different format, it'd be inferred as `string`