# Spark: not understood behaviour when writing to parquet file - datatypes

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a csv record like this :

```
--------------------------- 
name | age | entranceDate | 
---------------------------
Tom  | 12  | 2019-10-01   |
---------------------------
Mary | 15  | 2019-10-01   |
```

I read it from CSV and convert it to a DataFrame, using a custom schema :

```
public static StructType createSchema() {
    final StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(Arrays.asList(
            DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("age", DataTypes.StringType, false),
            DataTypes.createStructField("entranceDate", DataTypes.StringType, false)
    ));
    return schema;
}


sqlContext.read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
                .option("inferSchema", "false")
                .option("delimiter", FIELD_DELIMITER)
                .option("header", "false")
                .schema(schema)
                .load(pathToMyCsvFile);
```

Now I want to write this dataframe to parquet on my hdfs :

```
String[] partitions =
new String[] {
  "name",
  "entranceDate"
};

df.write()
.partitionBy(partitions)
.mode(SaveMode.Append)
.parquet(parquetPath);
```

But when I check the schema of the parquet in spark-shell :

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("/test/parquet/name=Tom/entranceDate=2019-10-01/").printSchema()
```

it shows the `entranceDate` is of type `Date`. I wonder how is that ? I already specify that this field should be `String`, how can it convert automatically to `Date` ?

**--------------**

**Edit** : I did some tests and found that it converts to Date only if I do `.partitionBy(partitions)` when writing. If I remove this line and print the schema, it will show the type of `entranceDate` is `String`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that happens because automatic schema inference mechanism. Spark documentation [page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery) says

> Notice that the data types of the partitioning columns are
>   automatically inferred. Currently, numeric data types, date, timestamp
>   and string type are supported.
>
> Sometimes users may not want to automatically infer the data types of
>   the partitioning columns. For these use cases, the automatic type
>   inference can be configured by
>   `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled`, which is
>   default to `true`.

Comment: @brest1007 You can change `spark.sql.sources.partitionColumnTypeInference.enabled` option using `SparkConf` object or via dynamically loaded properties when executing `spark-submit`. Take a look at [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties) page to find all the necessary details.